# Unknown Http Response Code Status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am trying to invoke a REST call to my server.
In chrome everything works fine, and I got status code 200. In IE I get unknown status code, and it consider it as 0 or -1. The response body in both case is the same, and contains legal json.

[image: img]

(Image link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1zrJ7GJMChTa25MOW1LdlJRRXc/edit?usp=sharing)

IE version is 11.
I am using angular to make the http call, and in chrome the callback gets to the success function and in IE the callback gets to the failure one.

The service code is:

```
service.signIn = function(email, password) {
    return $http(
        {
            method:'POST',
            url: '/users/session',
            params: { 'email': email, 'password': password }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: You should try to use Fiddler to watch for requests, find the request you wanted to inspect, and look at its raw HTTP response (request is at the top right, response is at the bottom right). That would be very useful to see what's going on.

Comment: What's the diffrences between Fiddler and the "network" tab of the browsers?

Comment: Browsers try decoding the response in a human readable format while Fiddler lets you see exactly what the server sent you (unparsed). This will let you see if there's anything wrong with the HTTP response, which seems to be the problem here. And even if that isn't it, you'll most likely see what IE is choking on and adapt it to work for IE. It would be good if you could post the raw HTTP response in your question if it nothing jumps out at you.

Comment: Actually you seem to be getting two different responses no matter what, so you should probably check into the server-sided code instead... And start debugging from there.